# Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I think i put the anonymous function in there wrong... when it outputs listzonebuffs it includes the function(){... part.

```
function load(zone){

setupzonebuffs(zone);

document.getElementById('zonetitle').innerHTML=zone;

listzonebuffs="";
if(zonebuffs['B']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+function(){if(zonebuffs["B"]>1){return "good";}else{return "bad";}}+"\'>Brute Force "+function(){if(zonebuffs['B']>1){return "+";}else{return "-";}}+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['B'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['W']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+function(){if(zonebuffs["W"]>1){return "good";}else{return "bad";}}+"\'>Wind "+function(){if(zonebuffs['W']>1){return "+";}else{return "-";}}+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['W'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['I']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+function(){if(zonebuffs["I"]>1){return "good";}else{return "bad";}}+"\'>Ice "+function(){if(zonebuffs['I']>1){return "+";}else{return "-";}}+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['I'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['E']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+function(){if(zonebuffs["E"]>1){return "good";}else{return "bad";}}+"\'>Energy "+function(){if(zonebuffs['E']>1){return "+";}else{return "-";}}+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['E'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['F']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+function(){if(zonebuffs["F"]>1){return "good";}else{return "bad";}}+"\'>Fire "+function(){if(zonebuffs['F']>1){return "+";}else{return "-";}}+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['F'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['R']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+function(){if(zonebuffs["R"]>1){return "good";}else{return "bad";}}+"\'>Earth "+function(){if(zonebuffs['R']>1){return "+";}else{return "-";}}+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['R'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['A']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+function(){if(zonebuffs["A"]>1){return "good";}else{return "bad";}}+"\'>Astronomical "+function(){if(zonebuffs['A']>1){return "+";}else{return "-";}}+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['A'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['S']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+function(){if(zonebuffs["S"]>1){return "good";}else{return "bad";}}+"\'>Stealth "+function(){if(zonebuffs['S']>1){return "+";}else{return "-";}}+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['S'])*100))+"%</span>";}
document.getElementById('listzonebuffs').innerHTML=listzonebuffs;

}

var zonebuffs=new Array();
zonebuffs['B']=1;zonebuffs['W']=1;zonebuffs['I']=1;zonebuffs['E']=1;zonebuffs['F']=1;zonebuffs['R']=1;zonebuffs['A']=1;zonebuffs['S']=1;

function setupzonebuffs(zone){
switch(zone){
case 'Mist':
zonebuffs['S']=1.3;zonebuffs['W']=1.1;zonebuffs['F']=.9;
break;
}
}
```

Comment: that's just terrible.

Comment: A few loops would do that code wonders.

Comment: The backspace key would do that code wonders.

Comment: I am aware of how bad that code is... right now i just want it to work...

Comment: Come on, give the guy a break. I agree it could be better, let's be more forgiving :)

Comment: I agree, o.k.w. We should be nice. But he's having trouble with it for the same reason we are--it's copypasta.

Comment: Well, at least the script Jcubed posted, I can use it wholesale (only lacking the HTML portion). If he were to 'shorten' it, we might not get a working version, though I must say most of the guys here don't even need to replicate the codes to try. It did it to catch any other problem. Having said that I still must agree that the formatting is well... much room for improvement. Hope the Jcubed will take note! :P

Comment: @Jcubed: Use = "I can use your code on my PC to replicate the error", What = "The code you posted", Where = "My PC"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should cleanup this code (honestly it's unreadable) and try replacing:
`+function(){if(COND){A}{B}}+` by `+(COND ? A : B)+`

Comment: Don't know if I've ever seen a case for using the ternary to make code clearer before. :-)

Honestly, I can think of ten things for him to do to clean that up before the ternary. #1 DRY!

Comment: @Jcubed: Glad you got your code fixed, you will need to get your code formatting fixed in SO next time yea? Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

That's because probably instead of appending the *function object* to the string, you wanted to append the *function call result*, that is, instead of

```
x += "<span ...>" + function() { ... } + ...
```

you probably wanted

```
x += "<span ...>" + (function() { ... })() + ...
```

However, I must say that your question isn't very obvious. Next time try providing a smaller sample with the localized problem and explain it more clearly. While doing that, most of the times, people end up figuring out the solution themselves...

Answer (score 3):

Mauris was on the right track, but there's still a "DRY" violation at work here.  That contributes a lot to the illegibility of the code.  Also makes it a lot harder to figure out what's wrong.

If you could resist the urge to cut and paste so much, and do a bit more thinking up front, you can save yourself a lot of agony and enjoy the process a lot more.

Here's my take on the code:

```
function goodOrBad (key){ 
    if(zonebuffs[key] > 1){
       return "good";
    } else {
       return "bad";
    }
}


function percentageFor (key){
  return (zonebuffs[key] > 1 ? "+" : "-") + " " + Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['W'])*100))+"%";
}

function textForZoneBuff(key, zone) {
  if(zonebuffs[key]!=1){ 
    return "<span class='"+ goodOrBad(key) + "'>" + zone + " " + percentageFor(key) + "</span> ";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

function load(zone){

  setupzonebuffs(zone);
  document.getElementById('zonetitle').innerHTML=zone;

  listzonebuffs= textForZoneBuff('B','Brute Force') 
               + textForZoneBuff('W','Wind') 
               + textForZoneBuff('I','Ice') 
               + textForZoneBuff('E','Energy') 
               + textForZoneBuff('F','Fire') 
               + textForZoneBuff('R','Earth') 
               + textForZoneBuff('A','Astronomical') 
               + textForZoneBuff('S','Stealth');

  document.getElementById('listzonebuffs').innerHTML=listzonebuffs;
}


var zonebuffs=new Array();

zonebuffs['B']=1;zonebuffs['W']=1;zonebuffs['I']=1;zonebuffs['E']=1;zonebuffs['F']=1;zonebuffs['R']=1;zonebuffs['A']=1;zonebuffs['S']=1;

function setupzonebuffs(zone){
switch(zone){
case 'Mist':
zonebuffs['S']=1.3;zonebuffs['W']=1.1;zonebuffs['F']=.9;
break;
}
}
```

Ahhh... now I can see straight again :-)

Comment: +1 What I was working on, only an even better example of the DRY principle.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was thinking. Except I would do array literal: [["B","BruteForce"]["W","Wind"]["I","Ice"]] and work from there.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary operator instead of function

When using anonymous functions, the value returned is a function.

Example:

```
var func_a = function(){
  alert('testing');
}
func_a();
```

In your case what you needed is to use ternary operator, which conditionally returns the value based on the expression.

`CONDITION ? TRUE : FALSE`, where based on CONDITION, value in TRUE or FALSE will be returned.

Your code, fixed:

```
function load(zone){

setupzonebuffs(zone);

document.getElementById('zonetitle').innerHTML=zone;

listzonebuffs="";
if(zonebuffs['B']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+(zonebuffs["B"]>1?"good":"bad")+"\'>Brute Force "+(zonebuffs['B']>1?"+":"-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['B'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['W']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+(zonebuffs["W"]>1?"good":"bad")+"\'>Wind "+(zonebuffs['W']>1?"+":"-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['W'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['I']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+(zonebuffs["I"]>1?"good":"bad")+"\'>Ice "+(zonebuffs['I']>1?"+":"-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['I'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['E']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+(zonebuffs["E"]>1?"good":"bad")+"\'>Energy "+(zonebuffs['E']>1?"+":"-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['E'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['F']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+(zonebuffs["F"]>1?"good":"bad")+"\'>Fire "+(zonebuffs['F']>1?"+":"-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['F'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['R']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+(zonebuffs["R"]>1?"good":"bad")+"\'>Earth "+(zonebuffs['R']>1?"+":"-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['R'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['A']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+(zonebuffs["A"]>1?"good":"bad")+"\'>Astronomical "+(zonebuffs['A']>1?"+":"-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['A'])*100))+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['S']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+(zonebuffs["S"]>1?"good":"bad")+"\'>Stealth "+(zonebuffs['S']>1?"+":"-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['S'])*100))+"%</span>";}
document.getElementById('listzonebuffs').innerHTML=listzonebuffs;

}

var zonebuffs=new Array();
zonebuffs['B']=1;zonebuffs['W']=1;zonebuffs['I']=1;zonebuffs['E']=1;zonebuffs['F']=1;zonebuffs['R']=1;zonebuffs['A']=1;zonebuffs['S']=1;

function setupzonebuffs(zone){
switch(zone){
case 'Mist':
zonebuffs['S']=1.3;zonebuffs['W']=1.1;zonebuffs['F']=.9;
break;
}
}
```

Please do the formatting...

And to reduce redundancy:

```
function cond1(val){
  return (val>1?"good":"bad");
}

function cond2(val){
  return (val>1?"+":"-");
}
function val1(val){
  return Math.round(Math.abs((1-val)*100));
}
if(zonebuffs['A']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+cond1(zonebuffs["A"])+"\'>Astronomical "+cond2(zonebuffs['A'])+" "+val1(zonebuffs['A'])+"%</span>";}
if(zonebuffs['S']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+cond1(zonebuffs["S"])+"\'>Stealth "+cond2(zonebuffs['S'])+" "+val1(zonebuffs['S'])+"%</span>";}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only create a function, whilst you shall call it - adding () after closing function definition solves the problem. But the simplier solution is to use

```
if(zonebuffs['W']!=1){listzonebuffs+="1? "good" : "bad") +"\'>Wind "+ (zonebuffs['W']>1 ? "+": "-")+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['W'])*100))+"%";}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be a good application for a function within a function. You might try something like this:

```
function load(zone){
        setupzonebuffs(zone);
        document.getElementById('zonetitle').innerHTML=zone;

        var oneCompare = function(val, onTrue, onFalse){
            return (val > 1) ? onTrue : onFalse;
        };

        listzonebuffs="";
        if(zonebuffs['B']!=1){listzonebuffs+="<span class=\'"+oneCompare(zonebuffs["B"],'good','bad')+"\'>Brute Force "+oneCompare(zonebuffs["B"],'+','-')+" "+Math.round(Math.abs((1-zonebuffs['B'])*100))+"%</span>";}
        //More...

}
```